# How to upload file to S3 (digital ocean) without saving temp file in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I need to save file in S3 Digital Ocean space by URL. It can't be downloaded and then saved to S3, because we use firebase-functions, and there restricted to use file system. Is there way to save it directly from url or other ways? For example by stream?

```js
const fileName = 'image.jpg';
const url = 'imageUrl';

const res = await https.get(url, (stream) => stream.pipe(res));

  await s3
    .upload({
      Bucket: 'name',
      Key: `content/${fileName}`,
      Body: res,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    })
    .promise();
```

Comment: Please post what have you done so far

Comment: so, i try to create a function which upload file by stream

Comment: added code in post

Answer (score 0):

All problem were in wrong path to `/tmp` directory.
[Docs.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-temp-files?tab=node.js) Final code for Firebase functions:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const s3 = require('../../services/storage');
const download = require('download');

const saveMediaItemToStorage = async (sourceId, item) => {
  // * creating file name
  const fileName = `${item.id}.${item.extension}`;

  // * saving file to /tmp folder
  await download(item.originalMediaUrl, '/tmp', { filename: fileName });

  const blob = fs.readFileSync(`/tmp/${fileName}`);

  // * saving file to s3
  await s3
    .upload({
      Bucket: 'name',
      Key: `content/${sourceId}/${fileName}`,
      Body: blob,
      ACL: 'public-read'
    })
    .promise();

  // * remove file from temp folder
  fs.unlink(`/tmp/${fileName}`, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('file deleted successfully');
  });
};

module.exports = saveMediaItemToStorage;
```